# Swift 5.4 UIImage animation: How to switch from bouncing (UIViewAnimate) to dragging (UIPanGestureRecognizer)

Tags: swift, animation, uiimageview, transition, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a UIImageView.

I can either get it bouncing by using animate:

```
        self.myImage.frame = CGRect(x: myImage.center.x, y: myImage.center.y, width: 50, height: 70)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse] , animations: {
            self.myImage.frame = CGRect(x: self.myImage.center.x, y: self.myImage.center.y, width: 70, height: 80);
            }) { (completed) in  }
```

or, I can drag it by using panGestureRecogniser:

```
    @IBAction func dragView(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
            let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
            if let viewToDrag = sender.view {
                viewToDrag.center = CGPoint(x: viewToDrag.center.x + translation.x, y: viewToDrag.center.y + translation.y)
                sender.setTranslation(.zero, in: viewToDrag)
            }
```

How do I switch from first bouncing and then to dragging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.allowUserInteraction` to your options when setting up the animation

```swift
self.myImage.frame = CGRect(x: myImage.center.x, y: myImage.center.y, width: 50, height: 70)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction] , animations: {
  self.myImage.frame = CGRect(x: self.myImage.center.x, y: self.myImage.center.y, width: 70, height: 80);
  }) { (completed) in  }
```

**EDIT:**
to break the bouncing animation loop use `self.myImage.layer.removeAllAnimations()` in the beginning state of the pan gesture like so:

```swift
@IBAction func dragView(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
            let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)
            if let viewToDrag = sender.view {
                if sender.state == .began {
                   viewToDrag.layer.removeAllAnimations()
                }
                viewToDrag.center = CGPoint(x: viewToDrag.center.x + translation.x, y: viewToDrag.center.y + translation.y)
                sender.setTranslation(.zero, in: viewToDrag)
            }
```